# I am unable to write data to Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Any suggestions about why it is happening.

I have used in the below mentioned manner:

```
FirebaseFirestore dbFirestore;
dbFirestore  = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

While Uploading I have used it in this manner:

```
documentReference= dbFirestore.collection("CLIENT_DETAIL").document(mAuth.getUid());
documentReference.set(userData);
```

I am not able to write it on Firestore, I tried many different possibilities.

However, sometimes it does write when I try to log in but not when the code execute while signing up. And when it writes and at that point, I am not able to read it even after calling with all the Field Keys.

Any suggestions?? Like why I might happen, or Do I need to have a billing account at GCP.
Please, anyone. It's been a day that I am trying to figure it out.

```
 mDocumentReferance.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            storeType= documentSnapshot.getString("STORE_TYPE");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: unable to fetch the document");
        }
    });
```

Its is the code for reading it but it doesn't work

Here is the Code on Task.isSuccessfull

```
 if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: creating folders based type ");
                OnAuth(task.getResult().getUser());
                sendEmailVerification();
                mAuth.signOut();
                SharedPreferences storeNamePreference= getSharedPreferences("UserDetails",MODE_PRIVATE);
                userData.put(RESTAURANT_UID,storeNamePreference.getString("UserUID",""));
                dbFirestore.collection("CLIENT_DETAIL").document(storeNamePreference.getString("UserUID","")).set(userData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: Database referance is created");

                        mDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: database referance is not created");
                    }
                });
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Since I have already saved the User UID value at SharedPreferances I an calling it there.
Did I do some wrong in the above code?

[image]

[image]

I do have the value of User UID.

Comment: I wanted to create the database the user signup is successful. However, after debugging I see that I am able to get the reference from the database. The issue is the data is not uploading from inside the createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method

Comment: I mean yes the log is mDocumentReferance.get().add().add();

Comment: did you enabled rules in your database to read and write when users are authenticated ? ,  did you added internet permission to your manifest?

Comment: @GastónSaillén, Yes I have added the Internet uses. Regarding the rules, I am not so sure about but it is saved as " allow read, write: if true; ".

Comment: I have added the code to create the Firestore Database inside " mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() " method so that I will be able to create the database when the user successfully signup which is not happening. But while debugging the references are called correctly and the Forestore database are created when I try to log in and not when I try to signup, and I get null acception along with it.

Comment: And after that when I run the app and try to log in still I get the null reference however I am able to see the value in the firebase Firestore database.

Comment: However, when I try the same app without the login or signup function I mean just a simple code to create and add value and read it is working fine.

Comment: Even if I try removing the intent.flag still the same I though maybe because of that. Still No result.

Comment: Anyone, why I am not able to write the database when I use the write method inside the mouth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() under the task.isSuccessfully ().  ??

Comment: Anyone?? Please I am unable to create the database while signing up

Comment: I have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419722/firebase-document-reference-does-not-work

Answer (score 1):

You can’t send data to Firestore, because you send to firestore false data. You send nothing, only `UserUID` field with no information:

```
userData.put(RESTAURANT_UID,storeNamePreference.getString("UserUID",""));
```

`UserUID` - is field which you send to dB.
Then you wrote “” - it’s false, because you’re sending empty info, you have to give variable.

Comment: I mean when I debug I can see the variable. I have called the Method "OnAuth(task.getResult().getUser());" inside this I have also called the method "OnAuth(FirebaseUser user)" and inside I have pass the user UID in to method "createAnewUser(user.getUid())" and the method createANewUser() accept string value which is user UID and inside of this method I have used the sharedpreferences to store the user UID.

Comment: Since I can't store the value in string before calling in firestore because we get an error of having more that one folder in documentReference, so I m calling it directly. I can share the screenshot if you want.

Comment: Please see the screenshot which I have shared in which I can see the value and I have stored it.

Comment: I have run the debug two time with different Email so the uid value is different on the screenshot.

Comment: I try moving the dialog.dismis() inside the method of creating firestore database, and I see that the Dialog doesn't get dismissed its seems like the method is not working. I have tried changing the documentReference into "USER_DATA" string, still the dialog doesn't get dismissed. ??? its like the method is not working when I use inside task.isSuccess while signing up

Comment: Okay, if you think its is null than how will I set the UserUID as the document reference while signing up????

Answer (score 0):

After continuous coding, I have found that it's not possible to call the Method inside "task.isSuccessfully" during the signup. What I have done is that in order to get the UserID outside the "mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()" method I have initialized the FirebaseUser and called the current user and I was able to get UserID. But Firebase takes around 2 to 3 seconds to load the UserID so I have added the ProgressBar which ultimately makeup the time to load and I was able to call successfully the UserID reference at DocumentReference.

WHICH SOLVED MY ISSUE.

However, I am only able to get the USERID while debugging, if I run the I get null reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set UserUID as the document in Firestore , write:

FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

-This currentUser variable - is the id of authorized user, his id in your app.

Then  write:
dbFirestore.collection("CLIENT_LIST").document(currentUser.getUid())
.set(userData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener) .......

-here you send user id as Firestore document.

*it works only when you have created mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword Method, because so your user will have his unique id.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and I get null when I run the app however if I debug I am able to get the value and save. I have tried that.